# C# calendar view in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, filereader

```
try
{
    Filehead();   
    var streamReader = new StreamReader(@"F:\PolarCycleFinal\PolarCycleFinal\PolarCycleFinal " + monthCalendar1.SelectionRange.Start.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy") + ".hrm", Encoding.UTF8);
    filetext = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
    richTextBox1.Text = filetext;
}
catch (Exception etc)
{
    MessageBox.Show("An error Occurred: " + etc.Message);
}
```

I'm trying to create a calendar view in Visual Studio where the user selects a specific date, and if the date file is available, it will display the data in a textbox.

So far I have the code above which opens a file dialog and then the user selects the file instead of selecting a date and then display the data.

[Screen shot of calendar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hhaEl.jpg)

Comment: I wonder why you are trying to reinvent the wheel, you already have `DateTimePicker`, you could use and create a custom control that internally uses it.

Comment: i'm not sure how to use the date time picker to load files

Comment: Write code to read and parse the file. Base on the data of the file and your requirements, setup the `DateTimePicker` properties.

Answer (score 0):

Drag your datepicker there, let's say its name is datepicker1.
Then in your code you can set its date as follow:

- `dateTimePicker1.Value = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-1);`
- `dateTimePicker1.Value = new DateTime(2012,05,28);`
- etc, reference: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime(v=vs.110).aspx

The format of the date in your file is up to you, then once you have the string content of the file, just parse the numbers (days, months, ecc) and construct the DateTime object as explained above.